# How to know which radio button is selected in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

here this is my code... here i am generating radio button dynamically using php code...

my problem is how to get which radio button selected on click of **addForm()** function...

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div> <input type="radio" name="form" value="Form-Name">Form-Name</div>
    <div> <input type="radio" name="form" value="Kalpit-Contact">Kalpit-Contact</div>
    <div> <input type="radio" name="form" value="Kalpit-Contact test">Kalpit-Contact test</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addForm()">Add Page</button> 
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var selectedValue = $("input[name=form]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 6):

You should do it like this:

```
var radio = jQuery('input[name="form"]:checked');
```

You can then retrieve your radio value or other attributes:

```
var value = radio.val();
```

It's a good idea to see if any radio is checked before doing that:

```
if (radio != undefined)
{
    //do what you need to
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can also try this -

```
    $(".modal-body input[type=radio]").each(function(){
        if (this.checked)
        {
            console.log(this.value+" is checked");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myval = $("#myForm input[type=form]:checked").val();
```

I would put in a div (id=myForm) and call it in the safety of the parent, just in case you have anything else on the page, like a newsletter signup or search box with options.